# How can we use "Set Variable if" with a keyword where Keyword is returning a variable RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

How can we use `Set Variable if` with a keyword, where Keyword is returning a variable that needs to be Set in `RobotFramework`.

Eg: `${Var} =    set variable if    ${i}==10    Keyword`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the easiest way to do it is by using `Run Keyword If` instead of `Set Variable If` like below:

```
Foo
    ${ret}=    Run Keyword If    ${i} == 10    Keyword Which Return Something
    Should Be Equal    ${ret}    something

Keyword Which Return Something
    ${var}=    Set Variable    something
    [Return]    ${var}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be the usage of "Run keyword if" with "set test variable" eg.

```
*** Test cases ***

foo

    Run keyword if    ${i} == 10    kw that sets test variables
    should be equal    ${var}    HELLO

*** keywords ***

kw that sets test variables

    set test variable    ${var}    HELLO
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is:

```
    *** Test Cases ***
    Test Case Title
        ${passed} =  run keyword and return status
        ...  Should be equal  ${i}  10
        ${var} =  set variable if  ${passed}  It is today

    Another Test Example
      ${var} =  set variable if  ${i}==10  It is today

    *** Keywords ***    
    It is today
        ${today} =  Get Current Date  UTC  result_format=%-d-%-m-%Y  exclude_millis=true
        [Return]  ${today}
```

Read further in the documentation 
[here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) and [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status).

Answer (score 0):

Just store the value from Keyword in a temp variable:

```
${temp} = | Keyword    | Param1 | Param2 | .....
${Var} =  | ${i} == 10 | ${temp}
```

If i is 10, ${Var} will be set to the return of Keyword.

Comment: Thanks OGrande, but here the Keyword will execute all 10 times, I need a solution where keyword also run and return value only once for the 10th iteration.

Comment: Just put the assignment of _temp_ out of the loop !

Comment: I think you meant `${Var}= | Set Variable If | ${i}==10 | ${temp}`